# Invertible Matrix and matrix norms

Tags: numerical-methods

I am studying numerical analysis and I have a problem with these questions:

$1.$ Prove that if a square matrix satisfies and inequality $||Ax||\geq\theta||x||$ for all $x$ with $\theta>0$, the $A$ is nonsingular, and $||A^{-1}||\le\theta^{-1}$. This is valid for any vector norm and its subordinate matrix norm. The second part I proved, but I don't know how to proceed proving $A$ is nonsingular.

$2.$ Also I have to prove if $A$ is diagonally dominant, then it will have the previous property.

I would like some clues for proceeding.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know that a square matrix is nonsingular if and only if it has a trivial kernel, i.e. $Ax=0$ iff $x=0$?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't realize that. I proved by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
$$
\|x\|=\|A^{-1}Ax\|\le\|A^{-1}\|·\|Ax\|.
$$

---

A diagonally dominant matrix is always invertible. Use the perturbation theorem in the row- or column sum norm or use Gershgorin's circle theorem on the eigenvalues.